# Macro / Google Sheets - How to duplicate/copy a row to the end of a list within the same sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

[Example - Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T6VjJ.png)

Hey,

I am trying to create a macro that will duplicate/copy a selected row to the end of a list (which is NOT the last row) within the same sheet. But so far, the only thing I got was to create a row underneath the selected row and duplicate it there.

Attached an screenshot as an example, I need to copy a selected row to the bottom of the list (row10 in this example) and not to the bottom of the sheet (row15 in this example).

Can anyone let me know where I'm going wrong and how I can fix it? This is driving me mad :(

This is what I came up with so far:

```
function Reschedule() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().insertRowsAfter(spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getLastRow(), 1);
  spreadsheet.getActiveRange().offset(spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getNumRows(), 0, 1, spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getNumColumns()).activate();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().activate();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.getRange(spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().getRow() - 1, 1, 1, sheet.getMaxColumns()).copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);
};
```

Thank you so much in advance!

Also, any alternatives that would help me to get the same result is very welcome too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your situation, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

```js
function Reschedule() {
  var activeRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange();
  var sheet = activeRange.getSheet();
  var row = sheet.getRange("A1").getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN).getRow() + 1;
  var dst = sheet.getRange(row, 1);
  activeRange.offset(0, 0, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).copyTo(dst, SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);
  // dst.activate(); // From your showing script, if you want to activate the appended row, please use this.
}
```

- When this script is run after a cell is selected, the row of the selected cell is copied to the next row of the last row of the sheet.

#### Reference:

- [getNextDataCell(direction)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getNextDataCell(Direction))

Comment: This crashes when I run it. The first line should be changed to SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getActiveRange(). But then it copies the first row, not the selected row, to the first unfilled row...

Comment: @Quaris Thank you for replying. About `This crashes when I run it. The first line should be changed to SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getActiveRange(). But then it copies the first row, not the selected row, to the first unfilled row... `, when I tested my proposed script, the script works instead of `This crashes when I run it.`. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your reply. Can I ask you about the detail of it? By correctly understanding your reply, I would like to try to understand it. If you can cooperate to resolve your issue, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it?

Comment: @Tanaike It worked, you are an angel, THANK YOU! But I ran into another issue, could you please check the answer I posted below and see if you can help me again? I was gonna comment in here but the message got too long.

Comment: @Jackonit Thank you for replying. From `It worked, you are an angel, THANK YOU!`, I understood that your question was resolved. I'm glad about it.

Comment: @Tanaike, sure, I completely understand!  I'm closing the question right now and I just asked the new one here: https://stackoverflow.com/staging-ground/74752643. Once again, thank you for your amazing support! I would be lost without you!

Comment: @Jackonit Thank you for your response. About your new question, when I accessed it, it returns "Page not found". Could you please confirm it? When I saw your posted new question, I would like to check it.

Comment: @Tanaike I'm sorry, I'm very new to this website and I might be missing something out. The page opens to me, I tried creating a question again, but it says I can only ask after 90 minutes, (so I believe that means the question was created the first time, but I'm not sure why it's not showing up to you, neither on my profile) maybe my question is under revision or something?

Comment: @Jackonit Thank you for replying. Although I'm not sure about the detail of your 
 current situation, in that case, how about posting it when you could post your new question? When I saw it, I would like to check it. And also, I think that in that case, a lot of users including me will be able to see your new question and think of a solution. So, please don't worry.

Answer (score 0):

So looking at the [insertRowsAfter](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#insertrowsafterafterposition,-howmany) function, the first argument should be set to the highest empty row.

How do we find the highest empty row? Taken from Tanaike's answer, [getNextDataCell](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getnextdatacelldirection).

I think your two .activate() calls are best left out--or do you need to change which cells are focused?

Finally, to copy the data, getting the source and target ranges and using getValues and setValues is probably the simplest way.

```
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  
  var firstColumn = 1;
  var lastColumn = sheet.getRange("A1").getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.NEXT).getColumn();
  var numColumns = lastColumn - firstColumn + 1;
  
  var sourceRow = sheet.getActiveRange().getRow();
  var targetRow = sheet.getRange("A1").getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN).getRow() + 1;
  sheet.insertRowsAfter(targetRow, 1);

  var sourceRange = sheet.getRange(sourceRow,firstColumn,1,numColumns);
  var targetRange = sheet.getRange(targetRow,firstColumn,1,numColumns);
  targetRange.setValues(sourceRange.getValues());
```

Example: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GxZdTBRsI20nTphqJIsEPONfMGY3E-BE1-zhgWCgnzw/edit